# SSRS adds return carriage to each cell when coping data from table in a report

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, carriage-return, ssrs-2016

I have a report generated with SSRS. I have a table that is generated with results (just like running a query in SQL Server Management Studio and getting results).

For some reason when I copy the data from the table in the report then paste it in Notepad it adds a return carriage to each cell. This does not happen when I copy from the results in Management Studio.

What the SSRS report generates:

[image]

SSRS table results copied to notepad:

[image]

Results from query in Management Studio:

[image]

Results from Management Studio pasted into Notepad:

[image]

How can I get it to look like the results I copy and paste from Management Studio? To be clear, I want to use the results from the FIRST image to paste into Notepad to get the results on the LAST image.

Comment: Why are you copying from SSRS to notepad in the first place? If you want to extract the data, use the export/save as function.

Comment: I'm not coping it to Notepad in my environment.  It was just an easy way to not have to explain to everyone that I have a proprietary application that needs the results in a text based format.  It was a way to have everyone to easily relate.  Yes I could use one of the 10 or so different export options then open those up and copy from it and get the results I need in the format I need.  But that causes more overhead and there should be a way in the report (even if I need to create a new page to do a text based data dump) that I can copy the output like I can from Excel/SSMS.

Comment: If you want to copy the dat, don't use SSRS. If you're using SSRS, use the save as feature, that;s what it's there for. Saving a file isn't over head... It's sensible. If you want a text form, i.e. a csv then use SSRS or SSIS to export the data to a file instead of presenting it in SSRS in the web portal.

Comment: Ok then I guess we can agree to disagree.  Because I can't see how it's "sensible" when it takes more time to accomplish a task.  I'm trying to leverage the reporting server to get my techs off the remote desktop accessing the SQL server directly.  Saving a file to copy/paste something is overhead indeed when the data is sitting on the screen staring you in the face.  Before I ever saved a file and went through all that I would rather copy it, open up Excel, paste it there and then recopy it to get the desired results.  The only reason I would ever save to a file is to...  Save it as a file.

Comment: Are you copying from Report Builder, Visual Studio, or on a Report Server? I haven't seen this behavior before so leaning towards a browser issue if you're on the server. Also, would a subscription of the report work for your use case to deliver the data in another format?

Comment: Great suggestion Steven!  I might be able to get away with a subscription.  Most of the time the report runs with static values but sometimes parameters need to be adjusted.  This is being ran on chrome accessing the report server via a browser.